# Frontispiece with absolute positioning, usage of the textpos package

Tags: titles, thesis, textpos

I would like to write my graduation thesis in LaTeX, but I need to make a frontispiece that exactly looks like this one made with Microsoft Word:

[image]

I've tried with some environments like `titlepage` and the package `frontespizio`, but the result is very different from the example given above.

So I've thought it would have been useful to use absolute positioning, but I can't understand the usage of the package `textpos`. Of course I don't want the code for a full frontispiece, but which is the code (for example) to get that "Università degli Studi di Salerno" at that height and at the center of the page?

Thanks.

Luigi

Comment: There are a lot of sample title pages floating around (e.g. http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/title-pages http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf ), which you could modify (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation has some good info on that).

Comment: As the author of `frontespizio`, I can only recommend it. ;-)

Comment: I add that with the `onlyinclude` option, you can use a PDF file built with other tools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment, I find title pages to be sufficiently individual as to warrant making them 'by hand' - I did this for your example below. I didn't have the Salerno logo so I put a box there instead but you can simple change the definition of `\plogo` to instead be `\includegraphics{yourlogo}`.

Hopefully it's obvious what you can change to finetune the layout.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand*{\plogo}{\Huge \fbox{LOGO}}
\newlength{\drop}% for my convenience
\setlength{\drop}{1em}

\newcommand*{\titleSal}%
{
    \begin{center}  
    \begingroup
    {\Huge\bfseries\rmfamily\scshape Universita degli Studi Di Salerno}\\[\baselineskip]
    \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\par %default baslineskip inserted between the rules
    \vspace*{\drop}
    {\Huge\bfseries\rmfamily\scshape Facolta di Economia}\\[\baselineskip]
    \plogo\par
    {\large\bfseries\rmfamily Corso di laurea in economia e commercio}\\[\baselineskip]
%   \vspace*{1cm}
    {\large\bfseries\rmfamily TESI DI LAUREA}\\
    {\large\bfseries\rmfamily IN}\\
    {\Large\bfseries\rmfamily STORIA ECONOMICA}\\
    \vspace*{2cm}
    {\large\itshape\bfseries\rmfamily Titolo della tesi}\\
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{2cm}   
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
    {\small\bfseries Relatore}\\
    {\bfseries Ch.mo. Prof.}\\
    {\bfseries\itshape Biagio DI SALVIA }
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright} 
    {\bfseries\small Candidato:}\\
    {\bfseries\itshape Nome Cognome}\\
    {\bfseries Matr.: }
    \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}  
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
    {\large\bfseries\rmfamily ANNO ACCADEMICO 2012-2013}
    \end{center}
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\titleSal
\end{document}
```

This produces [image]

Comment: Well, thank you. This will also be useful to learn, but it's a great frontispiece for my thesis.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem you have now when I wrote my thesis, but I didn't use any of the packages you've mentioned (probably they didn't even exist since it happened many years ago).

But I read this beatiful introduction to the LaTeX world (it is written in Italian!): [Una (mica tanto) breve introduzione a LATEX2ε](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/info/lshort/italian/itlshort.pdf) that helped me much.

At page 77 (93 of 109) you can find a description of the parameters relative to page layout:
[image].

If, for example, you want to reduce the parameter no. 2 of 1/2 inch you have to give a negative value to `\voffset` in this way:

```
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.5in}
```

But this is a very old manner to deal with these things. Nowadays packages like `frontespizio` (if you learn how to use them) will reduce much your work.

Anyway it has been nice to remember the days of my thesis.

Tanti auguri per la tua laurea!

BTW: I used the `titlepage` environment for that...

---

### EDIT

Despite you have already accepted an answer, this is my old code (1998) adapted to your frontispiece:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength{\voffset}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.2in}
\setlength{\textheight}{240mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{142mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.3in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.3in}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
  \bfseries
  \huge UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI SALERNO
  \vskip-.1in
  \rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}
  \vskip.1in
  \textsc{\LARGE Facoltà di Economia}
  \vskip.2in
  \includegraphics[scale=.2]{logoUnisa}
  \vskip.25in
  \large CORSO DI LAUREA IN ECONOMIA E COMMERCIO
  \vskip.7in
  \Large TESI DI LAUREA \vskip.1in IN
  \vskip.1in
  \LARGE STORIA ECONOMICA
  \vskip1in
  \emph{\huge Titolo della tesi}
\end{center}

\vskip1.4in

\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft}
    \bfseries\large Relatore:\par Ch.mo Prof.\par \emph{Biagio Di SALVIA}
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hskip.4\textwidth
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft}
    \bfseries\large Candidato:\par \emph{Nome Cognome}\par Matr.:
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}

\vskip1.3in

\centering
\bfseries
\Large ANNO ACCADEMICO 2008-2009
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Tanti auguri di nuovo!

Comment: This is even better than the one before. I've already accepted the first answer, so it would not be nice to change it and you already have a great reputation. And I think that your edit wasn't made to get more reputation,but just for kindness. Anyway, for what it's worth, you really have all my gratitude! :)

Comment: I've just seen that you're Italian too. Grazie mille :)

Comment: @Luigi I was watching Italia-Brasile so I hadn't the time to do that before... Don't worry about having accepted another answer. It's OK. You can always upvote other answers of mine when you find them interesting :-)