# reduce space at the top using maketitle

Tags: spacing, titles

I'm using XeLaTeX for my document and want to style my title page. The problem is, that `\maketitle` make a large top space, my text begins ca. 10 cm from the top. How can I reduce this space? In the moment it looks very crimped at the bottom.

Here's the explicit code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,ngerman]{article}
\parindent0pt
\parskip6pt
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setmainfont[Path = fonts/,
    BoldFont = akko-w01-bold.ttf,
    ItalicFont = akko-w01-italic.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont = akko-w01-bold-italic.ttf
 ]{akko-w01-regular.ttf}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Paket für die neue deutsche Rechtschreibung
\usepackage[...]{hyperref}
...
\title{Title}
\date{}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\input{./acronyms}
\input{./glosaries}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\textbf{{\large Thesis}}\\
\ \\
von

Name Name\\
aus City

Matrikel-Nr.: Number

{\today}\\
\ \\
\ \\
\textbf{{\large University}}

University long

University subtitle

Vorgelegt bei

\textbf{Name of the prof}

\ \\
\textbf{{\large company}}

department

city
\end{center}


\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{flushleft}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{images/university.png}
  \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{images/company.png}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29593/shift-title-and-author-text-up

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Include the `\vspace` command in the title command, i.e. change the line

```
\title{Title}
```

into

```
\title{\vspace{-2cm}Title}
```

Comment: it works too, used this way because the (rest) content is moved up too :)

Comment: and you can change the spaces around date/author as well and you don't need additional packages.

Comment: just saved the day for me! Thanks a lot. The answers here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29593/shift-title-and-author-text-up simply sound useless after reading your answer, no offence!

Comment: this is great works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 24):

The `titling` package can help you in this.

From its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.pdf):

> The `ti­tling` pack­age pro­vides con­trol over the type­set­ting of the `\maketi­tle` com­mand

In your case, adding these lines in the preamble (adjust `-3cm` to your needs) should do what you want:

```
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-3cm}
```

Have a look at the documentation for more options (e.g. spacing after the title)

Comment: For making a frontispiece, I would however use the `titlepage` environment, as you can see in these answers of mine: [answ1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122205/27635) and [answ2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120576/27635), or in several other answers in this site. I think you have more flexibility with it. :-)

Comment: I've added `\setlength{\droptitle}{-3cm}` and latex refuses to add a second page to the document, always errors with _undefined control sequence `\end{document}`_ as soon as the text exceeds one page

Comment: @msrd0 Did you set the command in the preamble? It is not meant to be used in the document environment.