# How do I move my logo up a bit?

Tags: spacing

I want to move the logo a little higher

```
% The default title page: title, then logo, then author
\newcommand{\@titlepage}{
    \begin{titlepage}

    % Make the logo
    \hbox{\hspace{30.0em}\includegraphics[height=1.5in]{\@logo}\par }

    % Make the title
    \makeatletter
    \centering{\LARGE \@title \par} \vspace{0.0cm}
```

Comment: For how to design a nice cover  see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120576/161015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hackily move things up a bit using \raisebox. For example,

```
\raisebox{1cm}[\height]{\includegraphics[height=1.5in]{\@logo}}
```

But you probably want to adjust the title page margins instead. See this post: [Different margins for title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31705/242407)